# Import contenful model from diferent spaces

Tags: contentful

I have a contentful model on one contenful space and I need export to another contenful space, Is this possible? there is any tool for this??? thanks in adveced there is a graphic tool?

I trie on the plataform but I cant, there is a graphic tool?

Answer (score 0):

We have the Merge App that allows you to migrate from one environment to another. This is not possible for spaces.

For spaces, you can use the CLI tool. You can learn more about it here: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/cli/import-and-export/